# Upload CSV file to SharePoint site Using SSIS

Tags: sql-server-2008, sharepoint-2010, ssis

Planning to upload CSV file to Sharepoint site thru SSIS.
It doesn't have to be SSIS but maybe writing SQL script or Shell script.
I have never written shell script before and dont know how to execute it.
Is this possible, if so how to do it. Any article or example would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: Any comments, Please!!

Comment: Do you just want to upload the file or extract data from the CSV and insert that into a SharePoint list? It's not clear exactly what you want to do.

Comment: Sometimes I want to upload CSV/Excel files to SharePoint(SP) site and sometimes i need to download Excel files from SP site. Files are usually stored in SP Library. I have SSIS SP Source/Destination controls now. I was able to download just plain data(not CSV/Excel files) from SP thru SP default view using SSIS SP contorols. That part works fantastic but i trouble uploading whole CSV/Excel to SP site or download/extract data from SP site. Hope this explanation helps. Thanks!!

Comment: I was able to download/transfer just plain data(not CSV/Excel files) to SQL table from SP thru SP default view using SSIS SP contorols

Comment: Hello Ola Ekdahl, Any comments please

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [SSIS SharePoint adapter](http://sqlsrvintegrationsrv.codeplex.com/releases/view/17652).

Comment: I made little progress and have already tried what you suggested. So far i'm available download/upload data from Sharepoint site, if it's a view and straight data but i have to upload csv/excel file to sharepoint site and that's where trouble comes in. I only have 3(Site URL, Site Name, ViewName) options on Sharepoint Source/Destination but don't know how to tell, just dump the file on sharepoint site because it's looking for output column mappings. Each upload/download file could be different.

Comment: Where exactly do you want to upload file? To the SharePoint list? Or as whole file to SharePoint library?

Comment: Basically i want to upload or download files from SharePoint site. I'm not good with SP in general. So to answer your question, it's SP Library. 1. Can i download/upload- transfer files to & from Sharepoint library using SharePoint Source/Destination task in SSIS. Let me know. 2.Do we need to convert or attach files to SP list as an attachment instead of SP Library. Please let me know your thoughts on this. Thanks!!

Comment: 1. I think no, you can't upload documents using SSIS. 2. It depends on your requirenments.

Comment: Can i download/extract file(csv/excel/or document) from SP site using SSIS and download the file to my local drive or export the data that exists in the file(csv/excel/or document) to SQL table. Let me know if that's possible and if there is a way to do it.

Comment: Hello Yevgeniy.Chernobrivets, Any comments please

Comment: Sorry, i do not know if this possible.