# SSIS SharePoint Integration

Tags: sql-server-2008, sharepoint-2010, ssis

**Tasks I am trying to accomplish:**

1. Upload CSV and Excel files to a SharePoint site
2. Download CSV and Excel files from a SharePoint site

**What I have done so far:**

Files are usually stored in the Sharepoint (SP) Library. I am using SSIS SP Source/Destination controls from CodePlex. I was able to upload and download just plain data (not CSV or Excel files) to a table in SQL Server from the SP site using these SSIS SP controls.

That part works fantastic.

However, I need to do the same for CSV and Excel files. The download destination can be a table in SQL Server. It can also be a CSV file or an Excel file.

**This is my question:**

- Are both tasks possible using SSIS?
- If so, what is the best possible way?

Thank You

Comment: Any comments or help on this.

Comment: Did you ask the [same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21238377/upload-csv-file-to-sharepoint-site-using-ssis) twice on accident maybe?

Comment: Download the CSV files using Powershell. Load the CSV data using File source adapter. You can call the Powershell script from your SSIS package using the Execute Process Task. http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/Copy-all-SharePoint-Files-0999c53f